# How to insert associative array into csv using thephpleague

Tags: php, arrays, csv, laravel-5, thephpleague

I have used thephpleague library into laravel5.1
http://csv.thephpleague.com/inserting/

I want an example to add associative array into CSV.
Right now I have used this functions
insertOne($array) for header of CSV and
insertAll($array) for their column values.

My code is -

```
    $path = public_path().'/csv/'.$filename;
    $csv = Writer::createFromPath(new \SplFileObject($path, 'w+'),   'a+');
    $csv->insertOne($headers);
    $csv->insertAll($data);
    $csv->output($path);
```

my $data array has an associative array (array inside the array) but insertAll() method gives me an error if $data has an associative array.

Please let me know how to deal with associative arrya?

Answer (score 1):

Transform the associative array to numeric indexed array like this

```
$csv->insertAll(array_map('array_values', $data));
```

Comment: How would this make sure they are in the expected order for the CSV columns?